# "Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [PreviewFilter]: could not be initialized"

Tags: websphere-8, websphere-portal

I've installed IBM WAS Network deployment(Application server) version 8.0.0 and IBM portal express 8.0.0. After successful profile creation When I hit the URL's of both the server. WAS URL is working and I am able to Login, but portal URL is giving following error.
URL:

```
https://localhost:10080/IBM/console
 - Able to login and working

http://localhost:10077/wps/portal - not working and below error on screen

Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [PreviewFilter]: could not be initialized
```

and logs from system.out

```
[18/06/18 15:04:26:423 BST] 0000012e PreviewFilter E com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl init(arg0) EJPSD0028E: The filter com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl could not be initialized due to error: The object or context preview does not exist.
                             javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: The object or context preview does not exist.; remaining name 'preview/PreviewModeService'
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.GenericPortalJNDIContext.lookup(GenericPortalJNDIContext.java:333)
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.GenericPortalJNDIContext.lookup(GenericPortalJNDIContext.java:346)
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.RootPortalJNDIContext.lookupObject(RootPortalJNDIContext.java:155)
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.PortalContext.lookup(PortalContext.java:72)
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.PortalContext.lookup(PortalContext.java:77)
at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:422)
at com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl$DefaultDependenciesImpl.<init>(PreviewFilterImpl.java:186)
at com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl$DefaultDependenciesImpl.<init>(PreviewFilterImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl.init(PreviewFilterImpl.java:264)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:145)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:600)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:507)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterInstanceWrapper(WebAppFilterManager.java:312)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChain(WebAppFilterManager.java:385)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:924)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)

 [18/06/18 15:04:26:470 BST] 0000012e webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError CWSRV0293E: [Servlet Error]-[portal]: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: The object or context preview does not exist.; remaining name 'preview/PreviewModeService'
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.GenericPortalJNDIContext.lookup(GenericPortalJNDIContext.java:333)
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.GenericPortalJNDIContext.lookup(GenericPortalJNDIContext.java:346)
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.RootPortalJNDIContext.lookupObject(RootPortalJNDIContext.java:155)
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.PortalContext.lookup(PortalContext.java:72)
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.PortalContext.lookup(PortalContext.java:77)
at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:422)
at com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl$DefaultDependenciesImpl.<init>(PreviewFilterImpl.java:186)
at com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl$DefaultDependenciesImpl.<init>(PreviewFilterImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl.init(PreviewFilterImpl.java:264)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:145)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:600)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:507)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterInstanceWrapper(WebAppFilterManager.java:312)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChain(WebAppFilterManager.java:385)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:924)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)

[18/06/18 15:04:27:993 BST] 0000012e PreviewFilter E com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl init(arg0) EJPSD0028E: The filter com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl could not be initialized due to error: The object or context preview does not exist.
                             javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: The object or context preview does not exist.; remaining name 'preview/PreviewModeService'
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.GenericPortalJNDIContext.lookup(GenericPortalJNDIContext.java:333)
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.GenericPortalJNDIContext.lookup(GenericPortalJNDIContext.java:346)
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.RootPortalJNDIContext.lookupObject(RootPortalJNDIContext.java:155)
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.PortalContext.lookup(PortalContext.java:72)
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.PortalContext.lookup(PortalContext.java:77)
at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:422)
at com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl$DefaultDependenciesImpl.<init>(PreviewFilterImpl.java:186)
at com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl$DefaultDependenciesImpl.<init>(PreviewFilterImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl.init(PreviewFilterImpl.java:264)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:145)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:600)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:507)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterInstanceWrapper(WebAppFilterManager.java:312)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChain(WebAppFilterManager.java:385)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:924)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)

 [18/06/18 15:04:28:020 BST] 0000012e webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError CWSRV0293E: [Servlet Error]-[portal]: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: The object or context preview does not exist.; remaining name 'preview/PreviewModeService'
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.GenericPortalJNDIContext.lookup(GenericPortalJNDIContext.java:333)
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.GenericPortalJNDIContext.lookup(GenericPortalJNDIContext.java:346)
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.RootPortalJNDIContext.lookupObject(RootPortalJNDIContext.java:155)
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.PortalContext.lookup(PortalContext.java:72)
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.PortalContext.lookup(PortalContext.java:77)
at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:422)
at com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl$DefaultDependenciesImpl.<init>(PreviewFilterImpl.java:186)
at com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl$DefaultDependenciesImpl.<init>(PreviewFilterImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl.init(PreviewFilterImpl.java:264)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:145)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:600)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:507)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterInstanceWrapper(WebAppFilterManager.java:312)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChain(WebAppFilterManager.java:385)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:924)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)

[18/06/18 15:04:29:945 BST] 0000012e PreviewFilter E com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl init(arg0) EJPSD0028E: The filter com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl could not be initialized due to error: The object or context preview does not exist.
                             javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: The object or context preview does not exist.; remaining name 'preview/PreviewModeService'
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.GenericPortalJNDIContext.lookup(GenericPortalJNDIContext.java:333)
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.GenericPortalJNDIContext.lookup(GenericPortalJNDIContext.java:346)
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.RootPortalJNDIContext.lookupObject(RootPortalJNDIContext.java:155)
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.PortalContext.lookup(PortalContext.java:72)
at com.ibm.wps.jndi.portal.PortalContext.lookup(PortalContext.java:77)
at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:422)
at com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl$DefaultDependenciesImpl.<init>(PreviewFilterImpl.java:186)
at com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl$DefaultDependenciesImpl.<init>(PreviewFilterImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl.init(PreviewFilterImpl.java:264)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:145)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:600)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:507)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterInstanceWrapper(WebAppFilterManager.java:312)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChain(WebAppFilterManager.java:385)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:924)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at
```

I've tried deleting "Temp" and "wstemp" folder as well, but that's doesn't worked for me. So can you help?

Comment: by the time it gets to here, it is because something else failed during startup, if you have the full systemout logs we can take a look there to see what failed during startup

Answer (score 0):

This has occurred for me previously due to two nodes starting up simultaneously. To fix, I shutdown both the nodeagent and Portal server on both nodes and started them one at a time. Node agent first then Portal server. Once open for business, I started the other node.